# integrate sentry with parse server

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-server, sentry

I’m trying to integrate sentry with my parse server which runs express server behind the scene. I’m not being able to send my parse server cloud function errors to sentry. Note that, we don’t need to write any error middlewares manually. Parse does it for us.

```
app.use('/parse', api)
app.use(Sentry.Handlers.errorHandler())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is Parse server option `enableExpressErrorHandler`, that does exactly what is required there - it pass errors to next middleware.

Just use `enableExpressErrorHandler: true` in your `parseServerConfiguration` dictionary.